# JavaScriptCore on iOS: JavaScript garbage collection failed

Tags: ios, garbage-collection, javascriptcore

We use `JavaScriptCore` to run most of the business logic in an upcoming app. Every now and then, the app crashes, with the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: JavaScript garbage collection failed because thread_get_state returned an error (268435459). This is probably the result of running inside Rosetta, which is not supported.
/SourceCache/JavaScriptCoreEmbedded/JavaScriptCoreEmbedded-1218.33/heap/MachineStackMarker.cpp(350) : size_t JSC::getPlatformThreadRegisters(const PlatformThread &, PlatformThreadRegisters &)
```

It's iOS, so it's definitely not running in Rosetta, and happens both in the emulator and on an actual iPhone.

It seems to happen mostly when uploading images using `URLSession`. We have made sure all calls into the javascript context are being made from the same thread, since we read elsewhere that callbacks from another thread than the originally calling one might give this error, but that didn't help. (And, according to `JavaScriptCore` documentation, `JavaScriptCore` should be completely thread safe anyway)

So, anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You should include a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Unfortunately, that's part of the problem, I can't currently find one, at least not without submitting more or less the entire application. We have crashes seemingly at random, and we haven't been able to track it down to what makes it crash. It crashes at different times, and on different calls. We are trying to find a minimal verifiable version, and if we do we have probably solved the problem as well, but for now, we haven't been able to...

Comment: So, basically, we're not looking to get a precise answer to what's wrong, since that's obviously impossible given no code example. We just want to hear if anybody knows any conditions/misstakes/bugs that make this happen. We have already heard that making callbacks from another thread can make this happen (which we don't), so, have anybody encountered other situations that cause this.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if JavaScript sets callbacks in Objective-C to listen for messages. Make sure that ObjC calls the Javascript callback on the same thread it was set.

Also post some code so that we can verify this.

Comment: Well, as I've said in the original post: "We have made sure all calls into the javascript context are being made from the same thread, since we read elsewhere that callbacks from another thread than the originally calling one might give this error, but that didn't help." That includes callbacks, sorry if that was unclear. Every call from ObjC to Javascript, including running the callbacks, are done from our javascript work thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across similar issues.

My solution was to ensure that the thread that created the context doesn't die.  It doesn't appear to have to do anything but I suspect that the error attempting to get the thread state is related to having the thread not be dead.

If anyone's curious about how I found this potential relationship, I refactored code to have callbacks run in the same thread that the interpreter was created in -- the darling solution of the community -- and backed out parts of the code in various ways to recreate the issue until I narrowed it to this.

If you need to keep a thread alive to test this for your situation, one easy way is with `dispatch_semaphore_wait` against a semaphore that will never be signaled (such as one you create just before calling `dispatch_semaphore_wait`).